# Validate uniqueness only on create - what am I typing wrong? Example provided

Tags: activerecord, phpactiverecord

I have this code :

```
 class Member extends ActiveRecord\Model
  {
   static $validates_uniqueness_of = array(
      array('name', 'message' => "That name has already been registered. Please choose another", 'on' => 'create'),
      array('email', 'message' => "That email has already been registered. Please choose another", 'on' => 'create')
   );
  }
```

The problem is that it checks uniqueness when I *update*. I don't want that. Only when I *create*.

What am I typing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :on => :create
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :on => :create
```

This should do the trick already, give it a try =)

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for an example using PHPActiveRecord.

Comment: My bad, didn't see the tag, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, that should work according to [the manual](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Validations#validates_uniqueness_of), but if it doesn't your best try might be the custom validat function, as explained in that link:

```
  class User extends ActiveRecord\Model
  {
    public function validate() 
    {
      if ( your_uniqueness_check_here )
      {
        $this->errors->add('namecheck', "can't be the same as someone elses.");
      }
   }
 }
```

Another option would be to update using the `save(false)` call, so you skip the validation. Is a bit tricky as well.